# Factorial of a number in pl/sql (Not showing the correct output)

Tags: plsql, oracle10g

I have written down a code in pl/sql but output is not showing
having trouble with this code.

```
declare

num number(20):= 0;
val number(10):= 5;
temp number(10):= 0;

function factorial (n1 in number)
return number
is
fact number(10):= 1;

begin
temp:= n1;
loop
  if fact <=0 then
     exit;
  else
     fact := fact *temp;
     temp:=temp-1;
  end if;
end loop;
return fact;
end;

begin
num:= factorial(val);
dbms_output.put_line('Factorial of ' ||val||' is '||num);
end;
```

Output:- Factorial of 5 is 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
if fact <=0 then
```

should be:

```
if temp <=0 then
```

You don't really need the 'else' part, because the 'if' exits the loop anyway; so you could do:

```
loop
  if temp <=0 then
     exit;
  end if;
  fact := fact *temp;
  temp:=temp-1;
end loop;
```

Or avoid the explicit check by using a while loop:

```
while temp > 0 loop
  fact := fact *temp;
  temp:=temp-1;
end loop;
```

... etc.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=16b82f3a857abde997e4765a92a8ac80)

Answer (score 1):

You are checking `fact <= 0` rather than checking `temp <= 0` and you should also declare the `temp` variable locally to the function:

```sql
declare
  val number(10):= 5;

  function factorial (n1 in number)
  return number
  is
    fact number(10) := 1;
    temp number(10) := n1;
  begin
    loop
      if temp <=0 then
        exit;
      else
        fact := fact *temp;
        temp:=temp-1;
      end if;
    end loop;
    return fact;
  end;
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('Factorial of ' ||val||' is '|| factorial(val) );
end;
/
```

Or, more simply:

```sql
declare
  val number(10):= 5;

  function factorial (n1 in number)
  return number
  is
    fact number(10) := 1;
  BEGIN
    FOR temp IN 2 .. n1
    LOOP
      fact := fact *temp;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN fact;
  END;
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('Factorial of ' ||val||' is '|| factorial(val) );
end;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=cedba10f06f064cfac76eded30fe81c7)*